# Are SQL injections still a threat?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-injection, cracking

I've been wondering if SQL injections are still a possible threat for everyday, normal websites, with parameterized SQL. (ASP.NET - '@0').

If it is still a threat, how would crackers override or get around these parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to OWASP, it was still the top threat in 2013 (long after ASP.NET came out): https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection

Parameterized SQL doesn't remove the need to worry about SQL injection. I have worked at a company where previous developers created stored procedures that took a string as a parameter, created some dynamic SQL including that string and executed it. They had claimed it was safe because it was parametised, but I was able to show that I could pass SQL code into the stored proc and have it executed.

Also, claiming that you are safe from SQL injection because you use a language that supports parameters doesn't mean that you are using parameters every single time. It only takes one slip up for someone to be able to inject some code into your database.

Comment: I think it is note worthy that using parameterization properly does effectively remove threats of SQL injection.  A hacker can't un-paramaterize something.
The situation you described is very specific in that the programmer more or less removed the benefits of  pre-compiled queries themself.  Valid, but probably not what OP was asking about.

Comment: Interesting. So SQL injections are more based on slip ups? Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @user2752635 Though if a string's contents can be misinterpreted as code, how would one avoid that?

Comment: The trick is simple: don't execute anything a user gives you.  Even if you put quotes around it, you're still compiling the SQL after the user input has been added.  In Greg's example, the parameterized SQL interpreted and ran another SQL script which included the user's input.  The point of parameterization is you interpret before adding user input so there's no chance of injection.

Comment: @AlexLeonardi I wouldn't say it's a "slip up", sometimes things are done intentionally by design (bad design, but still by design). Blanket statements of "we are protected because we use parameters" aren't always true.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, SQL injections are still a threat.  There are always new vulnerabilities found with these types of things.

Here are some reasons why injections can still be thought of as a threat.

- It's an easy attack, only one computer is required when others take many computers to attack.
- Bad programming, bad programming can lead to some easy vulnerabilities.  You have to make your database as secure as it possibly can to make it harder for attackers to find vulnerabilities.
- Trusting user input, sometimes trusting user input this much can really go wrong without any verification.

Those are just a few.  Remember though, if you're going to be using an SQL database.  Make sure that you consider the vulnerabilities in your project before you let the public use it.